# Using IF statement in Postgres WHERE clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've got a postgres table with user records in it. I want to select all records where the `last_visit` timestamp is within the last week OR the account was created in the last week. However, if a user hasn't visited yet, the `last_visit` timestamp is null (yeah, I know-- it's not set to default to the account creation date).

So I need to select all records WHERE *either* the `last_visit` is in the last week OR, if that's null, where `creation_date` is in the last week.

Something like this, although this doesn't work (and neither does a dozen other possible syntaxes I've tried:

```
SELECT * FROM users 
WHERE 
IF (users.last_active IS NULL) THEN
value(users.last_visit,timestamp(users.creation_date)) < current timestamp - 7 days
ELSE 
users.last_active < current timestamp - 7 days
END IF
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `coalesce()` for this:

```
where coalesce(last_visit, creation_date) >= current_timestamp - interval '7' day
```

`coalesce()` returns the first non-null value from the provided list. So if `last_visit` is null, `creation_date` is used. Otherwise `last_visit`

Comment: @DanBracuk: you are right. That should be "greater or equal". Thanks, corrected

Comment: It was wrong in the question and other answers also.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would probably be to `coalesce` those two values:

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
WHERE COALESCE (last_active, creation_date) < 
      CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '7 DAYS'
```